# How to refresh the angular formArray that using as datasource in material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms, angular-material-table

How to refresh the formArray in material table when we make new api call (Filtered data). If I click `Filter data` button, it should refresh and load new data from api. Currently its not refreshing material table and its adding new data into form array. How I can fix this?

Here is code: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrbkcc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

[image]

**Current behaviour of table**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove existing formArray by calling clear method on formArray. Then create a new FormArray then update the data source with new controls.

```
   onsubmit() {
     this.productArray.clear();
     this.formBuilder(this.sample2);
     this.tableDetails.data = this.productArray.controls;
   }
```

[**Forked Working Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aeszcs?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Its keep binding data in formArray(duplicating). How we can refresh the fromArray with new data?

Comment: Nope. When we click filter, it should load new data into fromArray

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that?
`this.tableDetails.data = [...this.productArray.controls];`

Comment: Nope, its not working. Its binding new data into existing formArray data. When u click `filter data`, u can see there row is keep increasing.

Comment: anything I missed out @chellapan?

Comment: what is your expectation clicking filter it should update old formarray?

Comment: I have updated my question with image. Please check

Comment: Update my answer please check

Answer (score 1):

You have to reassigned new data.

```
  onsubmit() {
    this.formBuilder(this.sample2);
    this.tableDetails.data = [...this.productArray.controls];
  }
```

I think you should refactor your code and use examples in mat-table documentation. I'm not sure it will work with Observable when you will make api calls.

https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-dynamic-observable-data